# Django app for loop through list containing a single dictionary

Tags: python, django, list, loops

I am creating a Django app to use json to parse data from the internet using an API. The Result is displayed in the form a a list containing a dictionary as follows

The following is the code used in the views page

```
    def home(request):
    import requests
    import json
    ####
    api_request=requests.get("xyz...URL")     
try:
    api=json.loads(api_request.content)
except Exception as e:
    api="Error"   
return render(request, 'home.html',{"api": api})
```

I am using the following code to render api on the home page. It renders flawlessly

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Hello World!</h1>  
{{api.values}}
{% endblock %}
```

The output is in the form of a list containing a dictionary as follows

```
[{'A': 53875881, 'B': 'cl', 'CH': -0.38, 'CHP': -0.00216, 'CLP': 175.46}]
```

I would like to get these values as follows

```
 A  : 53875881
 B  : 'cl'
 CH : -0.38
 CHP: -0.00216
 CLP: 175.46
```

I have tried the following code to loop through the dictionary contained in a list.I am not getting any output. Just an empty webpage

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% if api %}
   {% if api == "Error..." %}
    check your ticker symbol
   {% elif api != "Error..." %}
       {% for element in api %}
           {% for key, value in api.items %}
           {{ key }}:{{ value }}
           {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}        
    {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried other codes to loop directly through the list also.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% if api %}
       {% if api == "Error..." %}
        check your ticker symbol
       {% elif api != "Error..." %}
             {% for key, value in api.items %}
               {{ key }}:{{ value }}
             {% endfor %}       
       {% endif %}
     {% endif %}
 {% endblock %}
```

I request someone to take a look and guide me. I am unable to figure this one out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code seems to be ok, but you forgot to use the `element` variable in the nested for loop.

Try this :

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% if api %}
   {% if api == "Error..." %}
    check your ticker symbol
   {% elif api != "Error..." %}
       {% for element in api %}
           {% for key, value in element.items %}
           {{ key }}:{{ value }}
           {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}        
    {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Will try this sir.

Comment: Thank you. Can i request a short explanation as to why my code didnt work

Comment: variable "api" is the array, and variable "element" is for each dict in the array.

Comment: Many Thanks. many Many thanks